# Eigenvalues of square of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It can easily be seen that if matrix $A$ has eigenvalue $a_1$ and eigenvector $v_1$, then matrix $A^2$ has eigenvalue $a_1^2$ and eigenvector $v_1$. However, I was wondering if the converse is also true.

If I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^2$, then do I necessarily know $A$'s? If so, then how do you prove it?

Comment: Any eigen value of $A$ is a square root of some eigen value of $A^{2}$ but a square root of an eigen value of$A^{2}$  need not be an  eigen value of $A$ . Example: Take  $A=-I$.

Comment: Take $A=-I_n$. Then $A^2=I_n$.

Comment: Think of $1\times1$ matrices. If you know $A^2$ it doesn't follow that you know $A$. However, you would know the eigenvalues of $A$ up to a sign.